How to Retrieve Contacts from Directory Contact Folders in Microsoft Outlook Using Graph API?
In Microsoft Outlook, the Directory contains multiple contact folders, and each folder has its own set of contacts.
I want to fetch the contacts from the contact folders inside the Directory using Microsoft Graph API.
I tried using the "/me/contactfolders" API, but it only returns the contact folders under Categories and does not include the folders from the Directory. I searched through Microsoft's documentation but could not find any API or guidance specific to fetching contacts from the Directory.
I need to know if there is any Microsoft Graph API available to fetch the contacts from the Directory's contact folders.
If no direct API is available, is there any workaround to achieve this functionality?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can expand the contacts:
/me/contactFolders?$expand=contacts

or read contacts inside each folder
/me/contactFolders/{contact_folder_id}/contacts

The organizational contacts can be read from the endpoint:
/contacts


The Directory node in Outlook is your EntraId and the folders aren't real folders they are just filters of the directory itself eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-lists/address-lists. Eg Default Global Address list under Directory is every (non hidden) mail enabled object and all room is meeting rooms.
You can't enumerate those folders or addresslists using Graph (it make it hard if you trying to replicate the address picker in Outlook using the graph) you can search for Directory Objects using the people endpoint as long as you use the
"X-PeopleQuery-QuerySources"="Directory"
Header see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/people-insights-overview
If you need to specifically target a particular type of entry its better to use that endpoint eg All Contacts (will be you orgcontacts so use) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
or for (All Rooms) Meeting rooms use the places API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
If you have custom address lists  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-lists/address-lists that have more complex filters you could just use the exov3 cmdlets instead of the Graph or you may just be able to search the users endpoint in graph with a filter that is similar to what you address list does.
I wrote this one recently about my experiences with searching and discovering equipment mailboxes https://glenscales.substack.com/p/using-and-migrating-to-the-microsoft . Note the people endpoint in Graph is limited to the number of entry's you can enumerate
